# Erro acessando linha de JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

No meu sistema está dando erro na linha do código

```
ModelUsuario modelUsuario = new ModelUsuario();
    ControllerUsuario controllerUsuario = new ControllerUsuario();

    //recebe a linha selecionada
    int linha = this.jTableUsuarios.getSelectedRow();
    int codigo = (Integer) jTableUsuarios.getValueAt(linha, 0); //erro aqui
```

Estou tentando jogar os dados da tabela em um JTextField, mas, quanto clico no botão aparece esse erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que é essa variável linha? Qual a origem dela? Adicione na pergunta também.

Comment: ModelUsuario modelUsuario = new ModelUsuario();
        ControllerUsuario controllerUsuario = new ControllerUsuario();

        //recebe a linha selecionada
        int linha = this.jTableUsuarios.getSelectedRow();

Comment: Por favor, adicione um **[mcve]** do seu código, para que seja possivel reproduzir o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Olhando pela sua imagem diria que você está tentando pegar o index da linha selecionada quando não se tem nenhuma linha selecionada, veja na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow()):

> ```
> public int getSelectedRow()
> ```
>
> Returns the index of the first selected row, -1 if no row is selected.

Quando você tenta pegar a linha selecionada com `getValueAt()` e o index `-1` ele te retorna um `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index`.

Para solucionar verifique antes do `getValueAt()` se o index é maior ou igual a 0, caso contrário trate a situação, como por exemplo exibindo uma mensagem avisando que o usuário deve selecionar uma linha antes de clicar no botão.